# jQuery fontscale plugin

Tags: jquery, fonts, colors

I am trying to add functionality to the awesome fontscale plugin but I'm not entirely sure how to do it...

I've modified it to also change the font color but it's not in $.fn.fontscale.change_color() or something like that, it's just at the end of the code.

Modified JS:

[jquery.fontscale.js](http://students.cmps.subr.edu/aaron.chauvin/js/jquery.fontscale.js)

I want to put the code that changes the font color in a function similar to the functions used for the scale effects so as to fully integrate it into the script, complete with the saving of the color settings in the cookie, but I'm not entirely sure how to go about doing this.

Could anyone give me some pointers? Specifically pertaining to what arguments $.fn.fontscale.change_color() would have to take and how to properly write the color change settings to the cookie.

Comment: I don't want someone to actually modify the code for me, I just need some pointers and I'll code it myself. I'm just not familiar with writing to cookies and the syntax of functions/args in JS/jQuery…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I just wrote a plugin that's similar in structure to fontscale which handles the text color.

Comment: Would you consider posting the plugin you wrote for those of us that want to see the solution?  Or is it already in the link you had in the question?

Comment: I currently don't have access to the un-minified version but here's the minified JS... http://students.cmps.subr.edu/aaron.chauvin/js/coloropts.js

I'll add the readable version when I can get to it.